# Reset form method not working in timepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to reset the form value when clicking the reset button. But when I reset the form that time rest of the form fields reset except the time picker field.

I am using controller hooks form and MUI TimePicker.

```
import { useFormContext, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { TimePicker } from '@mui/lab';

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const methods = useFormContext();
const { formState, watch, getValues, reset } = methods;
const { isValid, dirtyFields } = formState;

const [morningShiftStartValue, setMorningShiftStartValue] = useState(null));


<Controller
    name="morningShiftStartTime"
    id="morningShiftStartTime"
    control={control}
    render={({ field }) => (
        <TimePicker
        name="morningShiftStartTime"
        label="Morning Shift Start Time"
        value={morningShiftStartValue}
        ampm={false}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          field.onChange(newValue);
          setMorningShiftStartValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(field) => <TextField {...field} />}
      />
    )}
  />
```

Also set initial default value null or "" but still not worked.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the components you are using `Controller` and `TimePicker` where do they come from?

Comment: @tsamridh86 using MUI TimePicker and react-hook-form for Controller.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are storing value of your `timePicker` in `useState` instead of in `Controller` (i suppose that you are using hookform). Just take value to takepicker from Controller

```
value={field.value}
```

or you can just destructuralize whole value in your `TimePicker` if there is no need to keep value separately

```
<Controller
    name="morningShiftStartTime"
    id="morningShiftStartTime"
    control={control}
    render={({field:{onChange, ...field}}) => (
        <TimePicker
        name="morningShiftStartTime"
        label="Morning Shift Start Time"
        ampm={false}
        renderInput={(field) => <TextField {...field} />}
        onChange={(e)=>onChange(e.target.value)}
        {...field}
      />
    )}
  />
```

Comment: I tried above mention both methods but still not worked. Using second method I can't select time without using onChange.

Comment: onChange is contained inside `{...field}` but you propably must edit it your way... you can destructuralize it in props of render: `render={({field:{onChange, ...field}})=>...` and then above `{...field}` use it based on API of TimePicker: `onChange={(e)=>onChange(e.target.value)}`

Comment: yes, now working. thank you for your support.